# XPath lookup doesn't work in PhantomJS

Tags: xpath, phantomjs

I'm trying to get XPath working with PhantomJS 1.9.2:

```
var getElementsByXPath = function(xPath) {
  return document.evaluate(
    xPath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
};
var root = getElementsByXPath("//div").iterateNext();
```

This is being executed upon page load and always returns null whereas querySelector seems to work correctly:

```
var divs = page.evaluate(function(s) {
  return document.querySelector(s);
}, 'div');
```

Did I miss something in this particular XPath evaluate sample?

Comment: Which MIME type does the document have? Does it use namespaces e.g. `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</html>`?

Comment: I tried it with google.com for instance and with many other sites. Same results.

Comment: Does MIME type affect XPath implementation in WebKit at all? PhantomJS site says it has native support for DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG. Does it mean it has no built-in capability for XPath?

Comment: I am not familiar with PhantomJS, my comment is just an attempt to point out the usual caveats when doing XPath over HTML, like namespaces and application/xml versus text/html. What happens if you use `//*` as the path?

Comment: //* returns [object HTMLHtmlElement]. When I try to iterate over its childNodes, it returns [object HTMLHeadElement] and [object HTMLBodyElement] both of which have no children.
So it appears to be <html><head></head><body></body></html>.
What I have also found out, exactly the same code works just fine in Chrome itself.

Comment: I tried to output all children of document.body but it returns an empty list. So it looks like the DOM was not initialized yet for some reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have finally found out that the call document.evaluate must be embraced with a page.evaluate call like the following:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.evaluate(
        '//div',
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,
        null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get html content of a particular xpath with phantomjs.. :-)

```
var xpath= '//*[@id="2b"]';
var address= 'www.mywebadress.com';
page.open(address, function(status) {
      setTimeout(grabHtml, 2500);
    });

function grabHtml() {

var html = page.evaluate(function(xpath) {

    if (document.evaluate) { 
        var xPathRes = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
        if (xPathRes.singleNodeValue) {
            var c = html.singleNodeValue.innerHTML;
        } else if (xPathRes) {
            var c = "No content found!";
        }
    } else {
        var c = "does not support the evaluate method!";
    }
    return c;
}, xpath);

console.log(html);
```